# What is the quickest way to expose a LoadBalancer service over HTTPS?

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, https, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a simple web server running in a single pod on GKE. I has also exposed it using a load balancer service. What is the easiest way to make this pod accessible over HTTPS?

```
gcloud container clusters list
NAME              LOCATION       MASTER_VERSION    MASTER_IP     MACHINE_TYPE  NODE_VERSION      NUM_NODES  STATUS
personal.....  us-central1-a  1.19.14-gke.1900  34.69.....  e2-medium     1.19.14-gke.1900  1          RUNNING
kubectl get service
NAME           TYPE           CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes     ClusterIP      10.....    <none>           443/TCP        437d
my-service     LoadBalancer   10.....    34.71......      80:30066/TCP   12d

kubectl get pods
NAME                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nodeweb-server-9pmxc       1/1     Running   0          2d15h
```

EDIT: I also have a domain name registered if it's easier to use that instead of https://34.71....

Answer (score 2):

First, your cluster should have Config Connector [installed](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/how-to/install-upgrade-uninstall#addon-configuring) and function properly.

Start by delete your existing load balancer service `kubectl delete service my-service`

Create a static IP.

```
apiVersion: compute.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: ComputeAddress
metadata:
  name: <name your IP>
spec:
  location: global
```

Retrieve the created IP `kubectl get computeaddress <the named IP> -o jsonpath='{.spec.address}'`

Create an DNS "A" record that map your registered domain with the created IP address. Check with `nslookup <your registered domain name>` to ensure the correct IP is returned.

Update your load balancer service spec by insert the following line after `type: LoadBalancer`: `loadBalancerIP: "<the created IP address>"`

Re-create the service and check `kubectl get service my-service` has the EXTERNAL-IP set correctly.

Create `ManagedCertificate`.

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: <name your cert>
spec:
  domains:
  - <your registered domain name>
```

Then create the Ingress.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: <name your ingress>
  annotations:
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: <the named certificate>
spec:
  rules:
  - host: <your registered domain name>
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

Check with `kubectl describe ingress <named ingress>`, see the rules and annotations section.

**NOTE:** It can take up to 15mins for the load balancer to be fully ready. Test with `curl https://<your registered domain name>`.